# How to set content in UIScrollView to be in the middle so,user can scroll left & right in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a question about UIScrollView.I want to set the content in the middle of UIScrollView so, user can scroll horizontally left & right easily.ContentSize of the UIScrollView should be 3 times of the content.Below is the drawing :-

|---------------------------------ContentSize of UIScrollView-------------------------------------|

```
                |-----------content----------|
```

How to set it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand you want something like that :

```
|----scrollVIew.frame.size.width---|

|----------------scrollVIew.contentSize.width------------------|

                 |-content.frame.size.width-|
```

in which scrollVIew.contentSize.width = 3 x content.frame.size.width.

To perform something like that, first, set your scrollview.frame:

```
scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height);
```

Then create and add content view into your scrollView and set its frame:

```
CGFloat contentViewWidth = 200.f; // the width of your contentView
contentView.frame = CGRectMake(contentViewWidth, 0, contentViewWidth, height);
```

Finally, set the content size of your scrollview:

```
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(contentViewWidth * 3, height);
```

And if you want to center the content, you can manually scroll to the middle of your scrollVIew:

```
[scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(scrollView.contentSize.width * 0.5f - width * 0.5f, 0)];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `setContentOffset` method. There's another useful information on the [reference page](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiscrollview_class/index.html).